# How to get the open/closed status of an ngb-accordion

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I want to render two different icons/divs in the title of `ngb-panels` of an accordion depending on whether the panel is expanded or collapsed. The panels have some form content inside them.So when the panel is closed it displays one icon and when it is opened it must display the other icon.

HTML and CSS template example

```css
input[type="text"],
select.form-control{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="number"],
select.form-control{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color:rgb(31, 14, 187);
}
input[type="number"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color:darkred;
}
::ng-deep .collapse {
    transition: max-height .55s, opacity .35s ease-in-out;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block !important;
  
    &.show {
      max-height: 100rem;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  ::ng-deep .accordion {
    .card {
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .04) !important;
  
      .card-header {
        // padding-top: 0;
        color: #000000;
        padding: 0;
  
        button {
          padding: 1.2rem;
          width: 100%;
  
          span {
              color: #5f5f5f;
            float: left;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
          }
        }
      }
  
      .card-body {
        padding: 1rem;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
 <head><!-- CSS only --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
 <body>
 <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" [destroyOnHide]='false' [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
        <ngb-panel id="panel1">
            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
              <span *ngIf=""> <!-- condition when it is closed -->
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="20"
                  height="20"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  class="bi bi-x-circle"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"
                    style="color: red;border-color: red;"
                  /></svg
                >&nbsp;</span>
              <span *ngIf="" ><!-- condition when it is opened -->
                <svg
                  
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="20"
                  height="20"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  class="bi bi-check-circle"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"
                    style="color: green;"
                  /></svg
                >&nbsp;</span>
                
              <span>Primary Details </span>
              <span style="margin-left: 85%;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" style="color: black;background-color: black;"/>
              </svg></span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
             some content
            </ng-template>
          </ngb-panel>
          <ngb-panel id="panel2">
            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                <span *ngIf=" "> <!--condition when it is closed -->
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    width="20"
                    height="20"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-x-circle"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"
                    />
                    <path
                      d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"
                      style="color: red;border-color: red;"
                    /></svg
                  >&nbsp;</span>
                <span *ngIf=""> <!-- condition when it is opened -->
                  <svg
                    
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    width="20"
                    height="20"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-check-circle"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"
                    />
                    <path
                      d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"
                      style="color: green;"
                    /></svg
                  >&nbsp;</span>
                <span>Secondary Details </span>
                <span style="margin-left: 83.3%;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                    <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" style="color: black;background-color: black;"/>
                  </svg></span>
              </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>

               <form #form2="ngForm" style="padding-left:20px;">
                
                   some more content    
                     </form> 
            </ng-template>
         </ngb-panel>
          </ngb-accordion>
          </body>
```

So, at `*ngIf=""` the status of whether the panel is closed or opened is checked and corresponding span is rendered. Please help me with the best way to check this status of panel.I have observed there are a couple of questions over this but they are not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to an accordion in the `acc` variable thanks to this peace of code: `#acc="ngbAccordion"`. To check if a panel expanded, you can use `isExpanded` method.

```html
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" [destroyOnHide]='false' [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
   <ngb-panel id="panel1">
      <div>isActive: {{acc.isExpanded('panel1')}}</div>      
   </ngb-panel>
   <ngb-panel id="panel2">
      <div>isActive: {{acc.isExpanded('panel2')}}</div>      
   </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```